# notify me when a script is done

Tags: linux, bash, notify

I am using Linux.

So I have my run.sh as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Started"
./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 50 1 5 0 100 1 0
./eg Datasets/Klein_nb_P100000_dim100.txt 50 1 5 0 100 2 1
..
echo "Done"
```

I would like after all the programs are done, thus 'Done' will be written in the screen, to get a notification (a pop-up message, or anything that will make me understand that the script is done).

The script runs in a terminal, while I am in my browser or such.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/28772/reliable-alert-dialogs-from-the-shell

Comment: There isn't really a generic bash way to provide notifications outside of the shell itself. If you're only targeting modern X11-based desktops with specific facilities available, there's a lot more that can be done/said.

Comment: @starrify that's exactly what I wanted! Could you answer the question please? Moreover, I think you should include this link too: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620 Charles yes, you are right! However, tekknolagi's answer provide something that's already installed and seems to give you more options.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for pointing out this, and I totally agree with what you say. However I've also noticed that the OP has mentioned "a pop-up message" and "while I am in my browser" :)

Comment: @G.Samaras Thank you :) and I guess it's fine to leave it as a comment. tekknolagi's answer provides a nice approach too :)

Comment: Visual http://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu audio http://askubuntu.com/questions/409611/desktop-notification-when-long-running-commands-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu, you can try the `zenity` command to bring up a pop-up.

EDIT: Here's a link to the help page: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/

Comment: That's ideal. The notification seems to be just perfect for me. I would suggest you to include the manual in your answer: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/

Comment: @G.Samaras there ya go!

Answer (score 1):

You could send a mail, to one ore many people that should be notified.

You can easily send mail adding this command at the end of your script :

```
mail -s 'Subject' you@example.com
```

Type man mail for more information on how to use the command.

Comment: Thanks, but I am searching for something that would make me understand immediately what happened. :)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of script, you can add:

```
aplay music.wav
```

to play a music file when script is done.

Comment: This sounds like a fun solution! Moreover it may be better, because it can notify you, even you watch something in full screen, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Growl to be a great solution to this problem.  While originally a Mac thing there are growl implementations for Windows and Linux:

- http://mattn.github.io/growl-for-linux/

Personally I use a growl.sh I found on the net somewhere to ping my Windows box when a particular job/script ends.

The "Visor" growl display is difficult to ignore so I always know when a script has completed.

One can also pass a small payload to each growl message so having growl let you know which script was running and whether the script succeeded or not is also possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1.